# How do you get a custom element to load using Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have a custom element like the nav-bar in the skeleton-navigation except I am not using the router part. I can't seem to get it to fire any events.

Code:
nav-bar.html

```
<template>
  <ul id="topMenu"></ul>
</template>
```

nav-bar.js

```
 attached() {
    alert('test')
  }
```

Containing page:

```
<template>
  <require from="./nav-bar.html"></require>

  <div class="desktop" id="container">
     <nav-bar></nav-bar>
  </div>

</template>
```

Comment: Not sure why anybody voted to close this, it's a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you load the custom element using `.html` at the end of the path, Aurelia does not load the `.js` file. Just change your require element to the following, and it will work as you expect:

```
 <require from="./nav-bar"></require>
```

Comment: Ashley is correct - however be careful. Introducing a nav-bar.js file into the Navigation Skeleton breaks the binding in nav-bar.html to the `router` param in app.js.

Comment: Yeah, but then you just set up a binding for that. I do that in my "Standard Aurelia Intro" talk. Although half the time I forget to do that part of the demo.

Comment: Yeah ofc, I wasn't suggesting that it was a problem that couldn't be solved, or that it was bad practice - just to be aware that it'll break and need fixing :)